# Jquery AJAX not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am writing an ajax web application but for whatever reason when I perform a GET against an internal data service in Internet Explorer 9 (IE9) it does not work. This same call works perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I am using a localhost web server (wamp) for development and developing on the same network as the data service I am trying to hit. I am using Jquery 1.8.1 (I have gone back a few versions but still see the problem). My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                    var loginUrl = "http://omittedurl.com";
                    console.log(loginUrl);
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : loginUrl,
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(response) {
                            console.log("RESPONSE: " + response);

                        }
                    });
            });
```

As I stated before this code works fine on Chrome and Firefox. In IE9 when I look at the web debugger there are no errors in the logs. It is like IE9 is just complete ignoring the .ajax chunk. Things I have tried:

- Turn Ajax Caching Off
- URL encoded my request URL
- Went back to three older versions of Jquery
- Manually pinged my URL from IE9 (able to get a response)

Any ideas??

Comment: is this a cross domain request?

Comment: Does it stil do that when using the latest jQuery release 1.8.2?

Comment: Hit F12 in IE, then go to the Network tab.  Load the page and see what the request is doing.

Comment: @GungFoo: CrossDomain should cause issues in all browsers I think

Comment: Are you testing it with the console open? IE and console.log don't get along unless the console is open so either comment out the console.log line or make sure to keep the dev tools open.

Comment: @GungFoo: I have tried that..but I only get the initial fetching of the Jquery js file and the fetch of the index.html page. If I do any other browser I will see the GET ajax request.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Look's like its a problem with

**console.log()**

IE has no console object when Developer tools is not open.. Try running your code by commenting your console.log and try again..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var loginUrl = "http://omittedurl.com";
    //console.log(loginUrl);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: loginUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
           // console.log("RESPONSE: " + response);
           alert("RESPONSE: " + response)
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to use console , you need to define that first if Developer tool's is not open..

```
if (typeof console === "undefined" || typeof console.log === "undefined") {
     console = {};
```

Comment: I totally didn't see the `console.log`, this will cause problems in IE.  Good catch!

Comment: @Gromer have a look: http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/

Comment: @moonwave99, yeah, I've used a couple wrappers before.  Unfortunately, I'm not doing much javascript at all at my current gig, so random `console.log`s aren't hurting me too much.  I'm bookmarking that link.

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the help! I can't believe Microsoft let something like this go!

Comment: I had a console.log('msg') just before an ajax call, I spent nearly 8hrs, thinking it was a problem with my ajax code. Struggled a lot debugging with online virtual machine for IE. Finally found this answer! Thanks!!