# Highchart : get image url after exporting

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get image URL after exporting High-chart.

Code works on Firefox but not in IE9.

Sample code :  http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/DXQSU/

```
var options = {

    exporting: {
        url: 'http://export.highcharts.com/'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
};

$('#export').click(function () {
    var obj = {},
    exportUrl = options.exporting.url;
    obj.options = JSON.stringify(options);
    obj.type = 'image/png';
    obj.async = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: exportUrl,
        data: obj,
        success: function (data) {
            var imgContainer = $("#imgContainer");
            $('<img>').attr('src', exportUrl + data).attr('width', '250px').appendTo(imgContainer);
            $('<a>or Download Here</a>').attr('href', exportUrl + data).appendTo(imgContainer);

        }
    });


});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but charts are not stored on our server, so solution like 'download from link' is very bad idea. Every minute, images in temporary folder are removed and never come back. See [privacy disclaimer](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/privacy-disclaimer).

Comment: This is the one time process. we need not call the server every time to download the image. Firefox gives the image link to download where as IE9 not. not sure why ?

Comment: Read that [jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283). Try to use xdr plugin.

Comment: Is there is any sample code for IE9. We need to post the data on "http://export.highcharts.com/" which is again not our server.

Comment: You need to adapt your $ajax() to be compatbile with ie9, similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592209/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: yes, we need to make ajax call with crossdomain=true . Link to reffer : http://hemant-uniquescience.blogspot.in/2014/01/highchart-get-image-url-after-exporting.html#more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 is getting crossdomain error. I have tried sample code for IE9 solution.

by adding  :

`$.support.cors = true;`

**Link** :  http://hemant-uniquescience.blogspot.in/2014/01/highchart-get-image-url-after-exporting.html#more