# Export SVG image to Excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, svg, highcharts

I'm using the Highchart library and its module [(export-csv)](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) to export chart to excel.

I get SVG chart data (chart.getSVG()), and then modify export-csv module:

```
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.downloadXLS = function () {
    var svg = this.getSVG();
    var dataUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml,'+encodeURIComponent(svg);

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' +
            '<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '<x:Name>Ark1</x:Name>' +
            '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->' +
            '<style>td{border:none;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;} .number{mso-number-format:"0.00";}</style>' +
            '<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>' +
            '<meta charset=UTF-8>' +
            '</head><body>' +
            this.getTable(true) +
            '<img src="'+dataUrl+'" alt="file.png"/>'+
            '</body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) { 
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); // #50
        };
    getContent(
        this,
        uri + base64(template),
        'xls',
        template,
        'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    );
};
```

Using SVG data:

```
var svg = this.getSVG();
```

We generate a URL image:

```
var dataUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml,'+encodeURIComponent(svg);
```

And add that URL to the excel body:

```
  '<img src="'+dataUrl+'" alt="file.png"/>'+
```

But I can not export the image

any ideas?

THANKS!!

Comment: A PNG is not an SVG. You are trying to put SVG data into Excel as an image and AFAIK Excel does not support SVG.

Comment: I'll try convert svg to png or other image format. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627642/highchart-get-image-url-after-exporting Get the image url and set it into the excel