# $.ajax not working in IE9 in case of font url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, fonts

I want to **know the time taken for the font to be downloaded while using font-face**. Hence i am using the following code

```
$.ajax({ 
 async: true,
 type:'GET',
 url: "fontPath/font.woff",
 CustomData: {fontObjIndex: i}
 success: function() {
 console.log('font downloaded')}
});
```

so that i can **confirm** that a particular font has been downloaded in client side using font-face. 
This method works well in all modern browsers except IE 9. **Does $.ajax accept Font urls in IE 9?**

Note: It didn't enter progress or fail functions either.

Edit : Sorry i entered the code wrongly there. The error is not in that line as it works in all other browsers and it still persists in IE9

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
 async: true,
 type:'GET',
 url: 'fontPath/font.woff',
 CustomData: {fontObjIndex: i}
 success: function() {
 console.log('font downloaded')}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**IE has no console object** when Developer tools is not open.. Try running your code by commenting your `console.log` and try again..

If you want to use console , you need to define that first if Developer tool's is not open..

```
if (typeof console === "undefined" || typeof console.log === "undefined") {
     console = {};
```

**REF** : [Jquery AJAX not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592209/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-ie9)

Comment: There is no such errors or problems. i had no console and it still didn't work.There are no silly bugs and i find $.ajax not accepting font urls in IE 9. If anyone has a code that works in IE9, do share.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply the following code to work

```
$.ajax({ 
 async: true,
 type:'GET',
 url: "fontPath/font.woff",
 CustomData: {fontObjIndex: i},
 success: function() {
 console.log('font downloaded')}
});
```